# how do I get req.query nextjs api?

Tags: node.js, api, next.js

I have this API, and I am trying to get the query I pass in the URL (such as products?page=1&limit=10) but I keep getting an empty object

```
const handler = nc().use(Cors());
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
    await db.connect();
    console.log(req.query)
    const products = await Product.paginate({}, { page: 1, limit: 30 });
    res.send(products);
});

export default handler;
```

Comment: Can you paste your complete code?

Comment: I could, but what would you need? That's all the code I have in that api

Comment: What are these objects imported from `const handler = nc().use(Cors());` ?

Comment: I'm using next-connect and cors

Comment: Is this an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)? Are you correctly accessing the path, e.g. `/api/products?page=1&limit=10`?

Comment: Ok so if I go to `/api/products?page=1&limit=1` I do get a response back. 

I don't understand then how to implement it? In my API request the base URL is `/api/products`, so that's where the request is sent. When I try to just get the query from `localhost:3000/products?page=1`  it doesn't work tho

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(req.query.page, req.query.limit)
```

You can pass any props to your api

```
const desiredId = 'xyz'
'https://yourAPI/getSomething?any_name_you_want='+ desiredId
//in your api
console.log(req.query.any_name_you_want)
```

Comment: if I go to `/api/products?page=1&limit=1` I do get a response back. I don't understand then how to implement it? In my API request the base URL is `/api/products`, so that's where the request is sent. When I try to just get the query from `localhost:3000/products?page=1` it doesn't work tho

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have somehow managed to do it even though it probably isn't the best way. It works though and my main focus is not the backend, so I guess it's good enough

In redux toolkit query:

```
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllProducts: builder.query({
        query: (page = 1) => `${baseUrl}?page=${page}`,
    }),
```

In my index.js

```
const router = useRouter();
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetAllProductsQuery(page);

const handlePaginationChange = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPage(value);
    router.push(`/products?page=${value}`);
};
```

and my API route:

```
 const handler = nc().use(Cors());
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
    await db.connect();
    const products = await Product.paginate({}, { page: req.query.page, limit: 9 });
    res.send(products);
});
```